# easytable package and \colorrow

Tags: tables, color, rowcolor

I use the [`easytable`](https://ctan.org/pkg/easytable) package to make isometric tables. This package provide the `TAB` (with caps) environment to make tables.

In the same time I use the [`xcolor`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) package with `table` option to colorize cells.

The `\cellcolor` command provided by the `table` option of `xcolor` work correctly inside a `tabular` environment or other table environments except with the `TAB` environment.

As you can see in the following MWE, `\cellcolor` colorize the cell in the cell in `tabular` environment but not the one in `TAB` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[thinlines]{easytable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}


\begin{document}

\begin{TAB}(e,0.4cm,0.4cm){|c|}{|c:c:c:c|}
  T \cellcolor{blue!25} \\
  ~ \\
  ~ \\
  ~ \\
\end{TAB}


\begin{tabular}{l|c|r}
  \hline
  Some & \cellcolor{blue!25}coloured & contents \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

And this is his rendering:
[image]

So, how can I force coloration of a cell in `TAB` environment (with `xcolor` or other solution, it doesn’t matter)?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using the new `tabularray` package (see [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularray)).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
        hlines={0.7pt, solid}, vlines={0.7pt, solid},
        hline{2-Y} = {0.5pt, dashed},
        colspec={c}, rows={4mm}, columns={4mm},
        rowsep=0mm, colsep=0mm, stretch=0,
    }
    \SetCell{blue!25}T \\
    ~ \\
    ~ \\
    ~ \\
\end{tblr}

\begin{tblr}{
        colspec={l|c|r},
        rowsep=0mm,
    }
    \hline
    Some & \SetCell{blue!25}coloured & contents \\
    \hline
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

which produces the output
[image: Colored table]

Inside the `tblr` environment, you can use the command `\SetCell` to modify the apperance of the current cell. The `tabularray` package has different default specifications for spacing, so I modified some parameters to resemble the output of your example. Please have a look at the [tabularray](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) documentation for further information.

If you use these tables frequently, you could consider defining a new environment using these specifications as defaults.

```
\NewTblrEnviron{mytblr}
\SetTblrInner[mytblr]{
    hlines={0.7pt, solid}, vlines={0.7pt, solid},
    hline{2-Y} = {0.5pt, dashed},
    rows={4mm}, columns={4mm},
    rowsep=0mm, colsep=0mm, stretch=0,
}

\begin{mytblr}{c}
    \SetCell{blue!25}T \\
    ~ \\
    ~ \\
    ~ \\
\end{mytblr}
```

You can decide, which specifications to use as defaults. For example, if you want to specify the cell size for each table individually, just delete the line `rows={4mm}, columns={4mm}` and specify this in the argument of `mytblr` .